# Swift auto layouts change button position when some buttons are hidden

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-autolayout

I have custom `UICollectionViewCell` as `TaskCell` in which I have added 4 buttons.
All the Buttons are added programatically using auto layouts.

Now when I hide some buttons then i want the other remaining buttons to take a place of hidden buttons. Check following images.

[image]

Here you can see 4 buttons align to the right side by using trailingAnchors. 
Now if I hide the last two buttons which is a Rating and Delete then I want the remaining two buttons to shift to the right and take the place of rating and delete button.

Following image shows other buttons remain at same place when I hide rating and delete buttons.

What can be the best way to do this ?

I know one way where we have to store the trailingAnchors and set it's active property according to our condition.

like following

[image]

```
var deleteTrailingAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint?

deleteTrailingAnchor = deleteButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -8)

 deleteTrailingAnchor?.isActive = true
```

Now we have to manage `deleteTrailingAnchor` according to our need.

Is there any better way to solve this issue using `AutoLayouts`.

Thank you for help.

Comment: why not putting all the buttons inside a stackView ?

Comment: Add width Constraints  to Buttons and set  NSLayoutConstraint to that width constraint

Comment: use horizontal stackview

Comment: I tried `UIStackView` when there is only two icons left both icon occupies too much space because the width for stackView is initially for 4 buttons when 2 is hidden the whole stackview width is used for remaining two and gap between two buttons increases.

Comment: stackview may not be useful because in stackview you will face same problem when you hide other views

Comment: instead of hiding the button, you can set the widthconstraint constant to 0 for the button you want to hide

Comment: @DevilDecoder Not if you remove the button from stack view.

Comment: what do you mean by  `"programatically using auto layouts"`

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz it means i have written code to place element in view i am not using storyboards for designing the views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIStackView` will do what you want.

Give it Top, Bottom and Trailing constraints, but ***NOT*** a Width constraint.

As you add / remove arranged subviews, it will remain "right-aligned" in the cell.

Here, I have 4 UIImageViews "a" "b" "c" and "d". The image views have width constraints of 30, and aspect ratio constraints of 1:1.

First, all 4 image views are in the stack view:

[image]

Next, I've removed "c":

[image]

And now, I've removed "a" and "c":

[image]

As you can see, the stack view handles the placement of the image views for you.

Comment: This  works great i have removed widthConstraints for `UIStackView` and now it adjust it self according to size of it's content.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add width constraints to all buttons (also set spaces between buttons to 0 and let them align one next to another). Then when you need to hide one (or several) just set `isHidden` to `true` and width constraint value to 0 for one (or several buttons). They will hide and all other buttons will layout for a new position. It would look much better if you will animate it with `UIView.animate(withDuration:, animations:)`